# Why does this C program print 6?

Tags: c

I don't understand why it prints `6` and not `-8`. If I understand correctly, `x % 2` is equal to `0` so I have to look for the case `0` right?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int x = 2;
    int a = 1;

    switch (x % 2 == 0) {
        case 3:
            a=a+3;
        case 0:
            a=a-4;
        case 6:
            a=a-5;
            break;
        case 7:
            a=a-2;
        case 1:
            a=a+2;
        case 4:
            a=a+3;
            break;
        case 9:
            a=a+4;
        case 8:
            a=a-2;
        case 5:
            a=a+3;
            break;
        case 2:
            a=a+1;
        default:
            a=a+4;
            break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x%2` is 0, correct. So what is `x%2 == 0`?

Comment: is it actually defined in the spec whether `x%2 == 0` equals any particular nonzero value?

Comment: @erik258: C 2018 6.5.9 specifies the equality operators, and paragraph 4 says “… Each of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false…”

Comment: Use a debugger a go executing you code by lines.

Answer (score 8):

For `x == 2`, `switch(x%2 == 0)` evaluates to `switch(1)`, and then execution continues at `case 1:`, which adds 2 to `a`, and as the addition is not followed by a `break` statement, execution falls through to case 4, adding 3 to `a`, after which it continues at the closing brace of the `switch` statement, and 6 gets printed.